# Shopware 6 : how to route shopware unit test output from fixture to original folder?

Tags: shopware

I'm building unit test for feature of get files from downloads folder under public directory. But in the unit test , i'm using fixture for test files path. how i can mockup directory in my common function beetween fixture and the original pub directory?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this core test: `\Shopware\CI\Test\Service\ReleasePrepareServiceTest::setUp`

They use the following code to simulate folder contents:

```
public function setUp(): void
{
    $this->artifactsFilesystem = new Filesystem(new MemoryAdapter());

    [...]

    $this->artifactsFilesystem->put('install.zip', random_bytes(1024 * 1024 * 2 + 11));
    $this->artifactsFilesystem->put('install.tar.xz', random_bytes(1024 + 11));
    $this->artifactsFilesystem->put('update.zip', random_bytes(1024 * 1024 + 13));
}
```

The unit tests creates some in-memory file system here and fills it with some files with random data.

I found this by checking the usages of the `Filesystem` class in the test folders of Shopware.

This filesystem can be injected into the service or code you are testing.

For example:

```
public function setUp(): void
{
    $this->myMockFileSystem = new Filesystem(new MemoryAdapter());
    $this->myMockFileSystem->put('file_we_need_in_the_test.pdf', random_bytes(1024 * 1024 * 2 + 11));
}


public function testSomething(): void
{
    $service = new MyService($this->myMockFilesystem);
    $this->assertEquals('some result', $service->doSomething());
}
```